# It seems that "-updates" repository is enabled during install, but disabled afterwards. How can that be?

Tags: apt, dependencies, official-repositories

I've had similar, strange dependency issues on very default packages (e.g. openssh-server or VLC) when I tried to install them after the first boot after initial fresh system setup.

It seems that higher-version packages were installed, but then their originating repositories disabled afterwards.

So the problem was solved by adding e.g. "bionic-updates" (for 18.04) or "focal-updates" (for 20.04) in **/etc/apt/sources.list**.

I don't recall enabling them during - or disabling after - installation...

Has anyone had a similar issue, or an idea what could have caused this?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

I've documented the error messages here:

- VLC (on 18.04):
  http://www.das-werkstatt.com/forum/werkstatt/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2596
- openssh-server (on 20.04):
  http://www.das-werkstatt.com/forum/werkstatt/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2629

Comment: VLC isn't a default package by a long shot. Please include the error messages in this post.

Comment: In 13+ years, hundreds of ubuntu installs, never had that happen. If you can document, ie fresh install, run sudo apt update & check output and or open Software Sources and see what's enabled, then file a launchpad bug

Comment: Perhaps you unchecked the source in the Software & Updates GUI while "cleaning up" or "customizing" -- that would comment out (disable) the source. Or perhaps you followed some online instructions without realizing their effect -- that might either disable or delete the source depending upon the command used.

Comment: Thanks for your replies!

So now I'm pretty sure it's "something" that I'm doing with package sources during install (or immediately afterwards). Interesting that I run into this in almost all installs I did in the last 2 years, although my setup-routine for ubuntu is pretty much the same since 2006:

I usually disable auto-download of updates during install, and then disable all auto-updates after install - then "apt upgrade" manually. Hm... Curious.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time to reproduce this issue anymore right now, but if I find out what causes it, I'll post it here too!

It's either something very trivial or very tricky ;)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: btw: I didn't find "focal-updates" in the Software & Updates GUI.
I wanted to enable it there (after install).

sources.list also contained only the deb-src lines for "-updates": Is that normal?
How do non-console users add the "-updates" repositories btw?